# Exhaustiveness and regularness of a filtration of a complex

Tags: ct.category-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry

I am learning spectral sequence, but I didn't find a "clear" definition of exhaustiveness and regularness of a filtration $F^{\bullet} := \cdots \subset F^{p+1} \subset F^{p} \subset F^{p-1} \subset \cdots$ of a complex $K^{\bullet}$. On wikipedia, a filtration is exhaustive if

> *the union of the set of all $F^{p}$ is the entire chain complex $K^{\bullet}$*

Naively, I think this means for any $q$, $K^q$ is the union of all $F^{p,q}$ (the degree $q$ component of $F^{p}$)

And in one another book, it's defined by

> For each $q$, there is a number $p(q)$, suth that $K^q \subseteq F^{p(q)}$

These two definitions are different. I am not sure about what "regularness" is for a filtration neither.

And finally, since we may work on an abelian category, and in this case, how do one define these two properties? Intersection may be defined by fiber product, but for the union?

p.s: I would like to know if there is a reference for spectral sequence with a good illustration of its power for computation. It would be great if it focus on "Leray spectral sequence" and using it to compute some sheaf cohomology (especially on schemes).

Comment: There is an unpublished but widely cited paper by Boardman which is an excellent reference to study these topics: http://hopf.math.purdue.edu/Boardman/ccspseq.pdf

Comment: Boardman's paper was finally put into print a little while ago, though it had indeed circulated unpublished for a long time prior to that.  It now appears in a book of AMS conference proceedings titled _Homotopy Invariant Algebraic Structures_.  It's not the place to look for examples, but I agree that it's a great reference for your other questions.